# Adding interaction in to a scene graph (in Haskell)

Tags: events, haskell, callback, event-handling, scenegraph

I've made a scene graph functional rendering engine in Haskell and am wondering how to add interaction in to the mixture.

At first, I thought I could just have another Handler node which takes in one of the other nodes and then just apply some IORefs to it. For example, if I had

```
x,y,z <- IORef 0
KeyboardHandler KeyboardCallBack $ Translate x y z $ Object
```

When traversing, I would have

```
KeyboardHandler keyboard drawable -> case drawable of 
Translate x y z _ -> do 
(Char 'q') -> x $~! (-1)
(Char 'w') -> x $~! (+1)
(Char 'a') -> y $~! (-1)
(Char 's') -> y $~! (+1)
(Char 'z') -> z $~! (-1)
(Char 'x') -> z $~! (+1)
render drawable
```

Is it possible to do something like that or am I going completely the wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

That approach might work, but there are better ways. I particularly liked [GLFW-b example](https://github.com/bsl/GLFW-b-demo/blob/master/src/Main.hs) that utilized something called [`TQueue`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/stm-2.4.4/docs/Control-Concurrent-STM-TQueue.html).

`TQueue` is short for Transactional Queue; it's something you can pass events into from the render thread, and then read them from the drawing thread. That way you can process them as if they were a simple, pure value; a list of events.

In general, Haskell favours pure operation to mutable state. The available rendering frameworks emphasize pure transformation of logical state to stuff on the screen. In this case, something like a `State OSG` monad  would be probably OK, though.

Comment: I'm not sure I get it. So I wouldn't use IORefs then, I'm assuming (Ideally, I'd prefer not to). I'm not sure how I'd use them in my scene graph, though. How would I implement something of the sought? Thanks, btw!

Comment: @Gentatsu `TQueue` is, inside, a clever `IORef` wrapper.

Comment: I'm still unsure as to how I'd actually use it, though? The GLFW-b example seems quite specific, so I'm not sure as to how I'd abstract it out.